Order of partial sums and Taylor polynomials in Taylor’s Inequality
Suppose $|f^{n+1}(x)|\leq M$ for $|x-a|\leq d$ (some closed interval about the center), then the remainder of the Taylor series for $f(x)$ centered at $x=a$ satisfies the inequality, for $|x-a|\leq d\space$, that:  $$|R_n(x)|\leq\frac{M}{(n+1)!}|x-a|^{n+1}$$
So clearly here it is crucial to get the value of $n$ correct when using this remainder theorem to bound the error.
Say we are investigating the error in approximating $\tan(0.2)$ with $P_2(x)=x$. Note here it is implied that $n=2$, although we could have used $n=1$ right since $P_n(x)$ is usually defined as $$P_n(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{f^i(a)}{i!}(x-a)^i$$
Similarly, a priori one would say that for $f(x)=\sin(x)$, we have that $P_3(x)=x-x^3/3!$, but can’t we actually say that $n=4$ and $P_4(x)=x-x^3/3!$ so we can get a better bound for $|R_n(x)|$?
